# How to executed Rez utility on OsX using cmake?

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I'm building an After Effects plugin on OsX.
The XCode project work fine and now I'm trying to port the XCode projects to Cmake environment.

One of the issues I have:
  - The XCode automatically executes Rez utility on .r(esource) files

Any ideas how to build the .r files with cmake?

Comment: Hey Yuri, Have you had any luck with this task? I'm trying to do the same thing but with photoshop plugin instead. I'm struggling a lot with xcode :/

Comment: Hey, sorry, even if I did it 5 years ago, I don't really remember what I've done there

Comment: Ahh bummer! Thanks for info tho! I'll keep banging the wall T_T Unless I can hire you to redo ur miracle? :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems CMake do not provide automatic resource file support in apple. You should use add_custom_command to run Rez at compile stage.